# is E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper﹕ Failed to get contextual suggestions. an actual Error

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a program that is taking a double from user input via a TextEdit and setting the value of a variable. Everything works fine, however whenever I press enter on the keypad I get this in logcat:

```
E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper﹕ Failed to get contextual suggestions.
E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper﹕ package name: myPackage.package
```

This is only happening on android 5.1.1 as far as I know. It does not do it on any of my KitKat devices. Is this a bug with Lollipop or am I doing something wrong?

Listener for the TextEdit:

```
    final EditText cutout = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.driver_manager_cutout_dimensions);
    cutout.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                ValueMaster.getInstance().setCutoutDim(
                        Double.parseDouble(cutout.getText().toString()));
                Log.e("KICKU",""+ValueMaster.getInstance().getCutoutDim());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

XML for TextEdit:

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="@integer/builder_tab_parameters_number_box_size"
                android:id="@+id/driver_manager_cutout_dimensions"/>
```